# Como localizar uma imagem sem informar o caminho absoluto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, imagem, drawing

Como localizar uma imagem sem informar o caminho absoluto?

```
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("~/Content/images/SemFoto.jpg");
```

Tentei de várias formas e não consegui capturar a imagem sem informar o caminho absoluto. A linha de código acima está em uma *action* dentro de um *controller*.

Comment: Não entendi. Se você precisa carregar uma imagem, precisa informar o caminho físico no servidor.

Comment: Você quis dizer: "Como localizar uma imagem informando o caminho relativo ao invés do absoluto"?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez preciso pegar a imagem através do caminho lógico de onde esta a imagem. Não o caminho físico referente ao disco.

Comment: * Caminho Físico (Physical Path): é um caminho do tipo do OS que aponta para um caminho ou arquivo no disco. 

* Caminho lógico (Logical Path): é um caminho Web que é relativo a raiz do servidor.

Comment: Bom, então a resposta do @bigown é o que você procura.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez OneSendai a resposta do bigown resolveu. Valeu pela força.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja:

```
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/SemFoto.jpg"));
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_MapPath_System_String_).

Tem algumas outras formas de fazer isto:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/RelativePath.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Web_Hosting_HostingEnvironment_MapPath_System_String_).

O jeito exato de uso depende de como vai precisar.

Comment: Resolveu @bigown Valew